# Why explicit type argument should be replaced by diamond?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, diamond-operator

I'm using Android Studio and I write this :

```
List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
```

I have this message :

> Explicit type argument Button should be replaced by <>

I'm curious, why would it be better to use diamond instead ?

```
List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
```

EDIT :
I don't agree with the duplicate at all ! I saw that answer before and it compares explicit argument to no argument at all, whereas I compare explicit argument to implicit argument !

Comment: It is not that you must do it, but it make your code nicer (shorter) so I have counter question: why not use diamond operator?

Comment: I'd think that more information is better for the compiler, but I don't really know how it works...

Comment: @DanChaltiel it makes the life of the compiler easier but you should demand more and more from your compiler:)

Comment: @SleimanJneidi Oh yeah, the compiler being hard-working isn't related to the final speed of my application, right ?

Comment: @DanChaltiel No, java is a compiled language, so this has no performance overhead.

Comment: Even so, this is a primarily opinion-based question, so it's still close-worthy.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It is less verbose, consider the following

```
Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
```

vs

```
Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

I think you would go for the second option

Comment: So not any difference except "beautiful" ? I'll go for it !

Comment: @DanChaltiel I guess you could also argue that it's easier to change later because you would need to perform the change on every usage of the explicit version. I mean e.g. changing from `String` to `Integer`.